# How do I make a conditional join?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT p.first_name || ' ' || p.last_name as full_name, p.user_id,
            u.email, u.username,
            (
                SELECT EXTRACT (year from (age(now(), p.date_of_birth)))
            )age,
            co.name as country, s.name as state, c.name as city,
            (
                SELECT country.phonecode FROM countries country WHERE ph.country_id = country.id
            )phone_code, ph.area_code, ph.number as phone_number,
            (
                SELECT i.path FROM images i WHERE i.id = p.image_id
            )avatar
            FROM people p
            JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id
            JOIN addresses a ON a.id = p.address_id
            JOIN cities c ON c.id = a.city_id
            JOIN states s ON s.id = c.state_id
            JOIN countries co ON co.id = s.country_id 
            JOIN phones ph ON ph.person_id = p.id
            WHERE (
                SELECT u.status FROM users u WHERE u.id = p.user_id
            ) = 'U'
            ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

However, some people don't necessarily have information in `Address` and `Phone` and I want to bring that information anyway, how could I do it?

Little example:

**Users**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+
| id | username  | role      |     status    |          email          |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+
| 7  | Shibari   | P         | U             | deathwrap@live.ca       |
| 12 | Josh23    | P         | U             | heeman@gmail.ca         |
| 13 | Test22    | P         | U             | test@gmail.ca           |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------------------+
```

**People**

```
+----+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+----------+
| id |first_name| last_name |date_of_birth|user_id| address_id | image_id |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+------------+----------+
| 7  | Edward   | Test      | 1983-10-13  | 7     |  11        | [null]   |
| 12 | Josh     | Test      |  1996-04-11 | 12    |  [null]    | 7        |
| 13 | Gavin    | Cringe    | 1991-04-11  | 13    |  18        | 8        |
+----+----------+-----------+-------------+-------+-----------------------+
```

**Addresses**

```
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------------+
| id | name                | zip_code  |     city_id   |
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------------+
| 11 | Rue De La Fonderie  |[null]     | 26497         |
| 18 | Av. Test            |[null]     | 6486          |
+----+---------------------+-----------+---------------+
```

**Cities**

```
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
| id  | name                | state_id  |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
|6486 | Resistencia         |210        |
|26497| Luxembourg          |2237       |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
```

**States**

```
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
| id  | name                |country_id |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
|210  | Chaco               |10         |
|2237 | Luxembourg          |127        |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
```

**Countries**

```
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
| id  | name                | phonecode |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
|10   | Argentina           |54         |
|127  | Luxembourg          |352        |
+-----+---------------------+-----------+
```

**Phones**

```
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| id | area_code | number    |  person_id    |  country_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
| 6  | 661       | 12345     | 7             | 127         |
+----+-----------+-----------+---------------+-------------+
```

**Images**

```
+-----+----------------+
| id  | path           |
+-----+----------------+
|7    | 7.jpg          |
|8    | 8.jpg          |
+-----+----------------+
```

**Here's the output I desire**

```
+------------+-------+-----------------+--------+---+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|  full_name |user_id|     email       |username|age|country   |state     |city       |phone_code|
+------------+-------+-----------------+--------+---+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
|Edward Test |7      |deathwrap@live.ca|Shibari |37 |Luxembourg|Luxembourg|Luxembourg |352       |
|Josh Test   |12     |heeman@gmail.ca  |Josh23  |24 |[null]    |[null]    |[null]     |[null]    |
|Gavin Cringe|13     |test@gmail.ca    |Test22  |29 |Argentina |Chaco     |Resistencia|[null]    |
+------------+-------+-----------------+--------+---+----------+----------+-----------+----------+
```

```
+------------+------------+-----------------+
|  area_code |phone_number|     avatar      |
+------------+------------+-----------------+
|661         |12345       | [null]          |       
|[null]      |[null]      | 7.jpg           |
|[null]      |[null]      | 8.jpg           |    
+------------+------------+-----------------+
```

At the moment it's just printing the first entry because it has both an address and a phone number linked, but I want to print this info even when there's no phone number or address linked, how could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left joins instead of inner joins:

```
SELECT ...
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = p.user_id AND u.status = 'U'
LEFT JOIN addresses a ON a.id = p.address_id
LEFT JOIN cities c ON c.id = a.city_id
LEFT JOIN states s ON s.id = c.state_id
LEFT JOIN countries co ON co.id = s.country_id 
LEFT JOIN phones ph ON ph.person_id = p.id
```

Using the above left join approach should ensure that every person record appear in the output even if it doesn't match to one or more of the otber tables.  Note that I have moved the check on `status` from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the left join with the `users` table.